# Need help in figuring how we got projection matrix error

Tags: linear-algebra

From the following notes 
[image]

it's not clear to me how you get final $P$

So we have

$$p = \frac{aa^Ta}{a^Ta} = Pb$$
so we get
$$P = \frac{aa^Ta}{ba^Ta}$$

Not sure how we get
$$P = \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}$$

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your confusion is caused by a typo. 
$$ \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{a}x = \mathbf{a} \frac{\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}}{\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{a}}.$$ 
We do not have 
$$p =\mathbf{a} \frac{\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{a}}{\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{a}}. $$ 
We can rearrange the correct expression for $\mathbf{p}$ 
(by just changing what we put in the numerator) and write it as $\mathbf{p}=\frac{\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^T}{\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{a}} \mathbf{b}$. Then, if we let $P$ be the matrix $\frac{\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^T}{\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{a}}$, it is clear that $\mathbf{p} = P \mathbf{b}$.